# I want a functionality using .net  to select an area by dragging at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to code in .Net to select an area and the area will be where ever in the form, that is not restricted to a control and asusually the area appears like a square by dragging using mouse at runtime on the form and if on clicking on a button for ex "Save" i.e., saving the selected area and when the next time the page loads that particular area should be clickable.Right now i have no idea where to start but if some idea is given it will be more helpful to me to develop some code for this functionality. Does any one give a small idea that how can I do this functionality, so that I can proceed developing code?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, but I can guess that it will come down to handling mousedown, mouseup, and mousemove events on your form.

Comment: Do you want to display a box as you are dragging?  What should it look like?  What do you want to select?  Just an "area", or a set of controls, graphics, or grid cells, etc.?

Comment: No, nothing else. In Paint if we drag some area then it will be selected as a Square, just as similar i want to do in windows forms in .net, just i am trying on that but have no idea where to start.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? What kind of area? What things does it contain that you want to select? Controls? Things you've drawn onto the form yourself through code? There's not nearly enough detail here to answer this question.

Comment: I came across a code for selecting area as a rectangle in CP discussion once, so I thought i could share it with you.

Comment: I love Stack Overflow for extraordinary working to be done.

Comment: Why after somany days Some one downvoted this question can that persons explain the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not my code ... [Select area](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3442443/Select-Area.aspx)

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            bool canResize;
            int mX, mY;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Purple, 2), rect);
            }

            private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                canResize = true;
                mX = e.X; mY = e.Y;

                rect.Location = new Point(mX, mY);
            }

            private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                canResize = false;
            }

            private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                if (canResize)
                {
                    if (mX < e.X)
                    {
                        rect.X = mX;
                        rect.Width = e.X - mX;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rect.X = e.X;
                        rect.Width = mX - e.X;
                    }
                    if (mY < e.Y)
                    {
                        rect.Y = mY;
                        rect.Height = e.Y - mY;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rect.Y = e.Y;
                        rect.Height = mY - e.Y;
                    }
                    this.Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank u for replying with a code @Karthik Ratnam, surely after trying this i will reply u.

Comment: Thanks dude its extraordinary, the code working fine. I have tested it.

Comment: It will be more use full for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are programming in WinForms or WPF, you can always catch mouseup and mousedown events, and their respective on-screen locations.
You could then ask every element on the stage if any of its corners are within the rectangular area between mouse-up and mouse-down point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Timothy Groote, let me try some thing like u and @Karthik Ratnam given ideas. Soon, i will reply back.